# What, if anything, is safe to symlink in /var?

Tags: centos, disk-space-utilization, daemon, var

We have plenty of space on a different mounted device. Since the /var partition stays relatively static in terms of size (around 8-10GB because of big logs that we need), I'd be fairly happy to simply make our current /var space 65% full rather than 75%. In other words, we don't need to move much. Here's a snapshot of what's in there now:

```
4.0K    ./account
119M    ./cache
0       ./clamd
292M    ./cpanel
8.0K    ./crash
12M     ./csectsh
528M    ./data
16K     ./db
16K     ./empty
6.1G    ./lib
4.0K    ./local
24K     ./lock
1003M   ./log
16K     ./lost+found 
0       ./mail 
120K    ./named
4.0K    ./nis
4.0K    ./opt
8.0K    ./portsentry
20M     ./pravda
4.0K    ./preserve
84K     ./profiles
236K    ./run
115M    ./spool
470M    ./tmp
4.0K    ./yp
```

We just repartitioned a bunch of stuff on our production server, so I don't really feel like scheduling more downtime, especially since I believe we have an SLA with a client. I know that many of these files' parent processes would have a problem with sym links, but I'm far from an expert, as this is an inherited system. Does anybody know any sure bets for things that can move?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd ***strongly*** suggest not symlinking, but using bind mounts instead.

That way the space is distinctly trackable rather than it being more wishy-washy as it is with symlinking.

http://aplawrence.com/Linux/mount_bind.html has a good intro to bind mounts.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have MySQL in /var/lib - move it to a different mount or set up a new disk for it. You can either symlink it or change the MySQL configuration.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing. We do this on a number of our servers as our database hd footprint has expanded. +1

Answer (score 1):

What is in `./data`?  That is not a standard directory and looks like a good candidate.  I would also suggest you dig deeper into `./lib`.  Something in there is taking up a lot of space and may be up for deletion or a move.